# How to make clickable buttons stay in place if they have long names

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating few buttons, and one of them gets replaced by a long named button. Basically when I click `click me` button, a button named `banana`, gets replaced by another button named `order apple, banana and orange`. The problem I'm running into is `click me` button moves away from my cursor position on the screen(on to the left side). I want the `click me` button and `apple` button to stay in place even after clicking `click me`.
Note that, on js side, I need to remove `banana` button off the DOM for future styling purposes. How do I go about this?

```js
var allDivsButton = document.createElement("div");
allDivsButton.setAttribute("class", "allbuttons");


var buttonOne = document.createElement("button");
buttonOne.setAttribute("type", "button submit");
buttonOne.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
buttonOne.innerHTML = "click me"
allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonOne)


var buttonTwo = document.createElement("button");
buttonTwo.setAttribute("type", "button");
buttonTwo.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonTwo);
buttonTwo.innerHTML = "apple"


var buttonThree = document.createElement("button");
buttonThree.setAttribute("type", "button");
buttonThree.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonThree);
buttonThree.innerHTML = "banana"


var buttonFour = document.createElement("button");
buttonFour.setAttribute("type", "button");
buttonFour.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
buttonFour.setAttribute("id", "button4"); 
buttonFour.innerHTML = " order apple, banana and orange "


document.body.appendChild(allDivsButton);


buttonOne.addEventListener('click', function(){
  buttonThree.remove();
  allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonFour);
})
```

```css
.allbuttons{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}


.buttons{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

edit:

I mentioned remove() only because I don't want style-display = "none" option on it.

Comment: is this your complete html ?

Comment: I'm not creating elements in html file. I'm appending the elements from js.

Comment: how do you call this function ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra What function?

Comment: @Deke Do you need it to be responsive? Like if you resize your screen on the fly that fourth button will be moved accordingly?

Comment: Yes it has to be responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var allDivsButton = document.createElement("div");
allDivsButton.setAttribute("class", "allbuttons");


var buttonOne = document.createElement("button");
buttonOne.setAttribute("type", "button submit");
buttonOne.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
buttonOne.innerHTML = "click me"
allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonOne)


var buttonTwo = document.createElement("button");
buttonTwo.setAttribute("type", "button");
buttonTwo.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonTwo);
buttonTwo.innerHTML = "apple"


var buttonThree = document.createElement("button");
buttonThree.setAttribute("type", "button");
buttonThree.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonThree);
buttonThree.innerHTML = "banana"


var buttonFour = document.createElement("button");
buttonFour.setAttribute("type", "button");
buttonFour.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
buttonFour.setAttribute("id", "button4"); 
buttonFour.innerHTML = " order apple, banana and orange "


document.body.appendChild(allDivsButton);


buttonOne.addEventListener('click', function(){
  buttonThree.remove();
  allDivsButton.appendChild(buttonFour);
});

var cloneall = allDivsButton.cloneNode(true);

document.body.appendChild(cloneall);

cloneall.setAttribute("class", "allbuttonsclone");

var clonebutton = buttonFour.cloneNode(true);
clonebutton.setAttribute("class", "buttons buttonclone hidden");
cloneall.appendChild(clonebutton);
cloneall.children[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  cloneall.children[2].setAttribute("class", "buttons hidden");
  
  clonebutton.setAttribute("class", "buttons buttonclone");
});
```

```css
.allbuttons {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.allbuttonsclone {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.buttons {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.buttonclone {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  top: 58px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Looks somewhat strange to me but it can't get better than this I think, at least according to OP's specification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the jQuery .remove() on buttonThree.  In javaScript you could use something like:

```
allDivsButton.removeChild(buttonThree);
```

You also need to look at the css.  The class .allbuttons has the attribute of text-align: center; which is causing the behavior that is causing the buttons to 'move'. You could have the buttons wrapped in an additional div that has a specific width so the buttons don't move.

Comment: hajile and raf...I found both your answers useful.